# Anime about a cop with a robot partner and a rampaging tank

Tags: story-identification, robots, anime, episode-identification

I have been searching for this for a few weeks and I am hoping that you guys can help me out.

I know that what I watched was a movie I am not sure if the story was self contained within the story or if it was a movie of a series like they did with Patlabor.  I am going to guess that the movie was mid 80s to early 90s.  The movie starts with a motorcycle cop getting in trouble for something I am not sure what exactly for but he ends up getting transferred to a special division of the police department.  He is one of three people chosen to work with robot counterparts.  His robot partners name was Blades I am pretty sure his colour scheme was blue and white and he shot hand cuffs out of his arms.

As for the story of the movie I am a little more fuzzy on that.  What I do remember about it is someone puts a computer virus type device into a new 1994 tank because they are trying to steal it.  The tank then goes rampaging through the city.  Someone finally gets inside the tank removes the control pad but by then it is too late and the madness continues.  I also remember the tank being able to do anything, it had inflatable sides to drive through water and lasers and missiles.

Also, the female officers robot was pink and had tentacle like devices that she used to hack computers.  The other robot was green and it was always trying to figure out how to properly use the wrist exercising device.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: The "tentacle like devices that she used to hack computers" remind me of _Ghost in the Shell_, but the rest doesn't add up.

Answer (score 15):

This sounds like it's [Techno Police 21C](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Techno_Police_21C), originally released in 1982.

[image: Techno Police 21C poster]

Some matching details:

- the main character, Ken, is a motorcycle highway cop. at the beginning of the movie, he is called to join the police force in Centinel City after getting into trouble for wrecking yet *another* motorcycle.
- he has a robot partner named Blader, who is blue and white and has a projectile handcuff
- another character has a partner which is pink and has cables which could interface with computers, streaming from its neck .
- the plot centers around a tank being hijacked
- one of the characters gets into the tank, but the tank starts up on its own and rampages through the city

Comment: This is it 100 percent thank you so much

Comment: Awesome. Be sure to accept the answer too!

Answer (score 2):

Dominion Tank Police (1993)
[image]

Dominion: Tank Police
Dominion tank police OAVDVD.jpg
Cover of North American Dominion: Tank Police DVD release.
ドミニオン
(Dominion)
Genre   Comedy, Science fiction, Cyberpunk
Manga
Written by  Masamune Shirow
Published by    Hakusensha
English publisher
NA
Dark Horse Comics
Demographic Seinen
Magazine    Young Animal Arashi
Published   1985
Volumes 1
Original video animation
Dominion Tank Police
Directed by Kōichi Mashimo
Studio  Agent 21
Licensed by 
AUS
Manga Entertainment (expired)
NA
Central Park Media (expired)
UK
Manga Entertainment (expired)
Released    May 27, 1988 – August 11, 1989
Episodes    4
Original video animation
New Dominion Tank Police
Directed by Norubu Furuse
Studio  J.C.Staff
Licensed by 
NA
Maiden Japan
Released    October 21, 1993 – October 21, 1994
Episodes    6
Manga
Dominion Conflict One: No More Noise
Written by  Masamune Shirow
Published by    Seishinsha
English publisher
NA
Dark Horse Comics
Demographic Seinen
Magazine    Young Manga
Published   1995
Volumes 1
Original video animation
TANK S.W.A.T. 01
Directed by Romanov Higa
Studio  DOGA Productions
Released    2006

Comment: While the author didn't technically accept it, he left a comment saying that the earlier answer was correct.